# How does this inequality of a complex function hold

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

I cannot figure out how $\Re[g(\lambda)]\leq |\lambda|$ implies $|g(\lambda)|\leq|2 r-g(\lambda)|$ where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary complex number s.t. $|\lambda|\leq r$, and $g$ is an entire function.  I tried all the elementary inequalities used in complex analysis, but I couldn't prove. Could anyone give me a hint? This is from the following lemma of Rudin's *Functional Analysis*. I don't think we need deep knowledge in functional analysis or properties of entire function to prove this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $\;x:=\text{Re}(g(\lambda))\;,\;\;y:=\text{Im}(g(\lambda))\;$ , then

$$|g(\lambda)|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

OTOH

$$|2r-g(\lambda)|=\sqrt{\left(2r-x\right)^2+y^2}=\sqrt{4r^2-4rx+x^2+y^2}$$

Thus, we have

$$|g(\lambda)|\le|2r-g(\lambda)|\iff x^2+y^2\le4r^2-4rx+x^2+y^2\iff x\le r$$

which is true since we're given

$$x=\text{Re}(g(\lambda))\stackrel{\text{given}}\le|\lambda|\stackrel{\text{given}}\le r$$

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help.